# How to get desired output from ForkJoinPool.commonPool().submit

Tags: java, parallel-processing, fork-join, forkjoinpool

Please consider the below existing code segment in the project.

`ForkJoinPool.commonPool().submit(() -> updateActions(a, b, c));`

public void updateActions(a, b, c){
--some implementation--
}

**updateActions** is a void method. I'm going to change it to output a **Map<String, String>** from it. I want to keep the parallel execution behavior as it is and get the map at the end of execution from that.

I modified the code as below but couldn't get any output from it.

`ForkJoinTask<Map<String, String>> output = ForkJoinPool.commonPool().submit(() -> updateActions(a, b, c));`

changed updateActions method is as below-->

public Map<String, String> updateActions(a, b, c){
--some implementation--
return map;
}

How can I change my code according to this requirement?

Comment: Neither `commonPool()` not lambda expressions exist in Java-7.

Answer (score 0):

realized that the output can be obtained **output.get()**. Thanks

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).